# Constant complex function with real part is greater than 2

Tags: complex-analysis

I have proved that if $\mbox{Re}(f(z))>2$ ($f$ is analytic and defined in whole complex plane), then $f$ is constant function:
$$|f(z)|\geq \mbox{Re}(f(z))>2\implies |1/f(z)|\leq 1/2<2$$

By Liouville's Theorem, if there exist an entire function $g$ such that $|g(z)|\leq C$ is bounded ($C$ is a constant), then $g$ is constant.  $g$ is the function that should be found.
I defined $g$ as follows :   $g(z)=f(z)+i$, assumed that $f(z)= x+i\cdot0$
$$ |g(z)|\geq \mbox{Re}(g(z)) \implies |g(z)|\geq\mbox{Re}(f(z))
\implies |g(z)|\geq |f(z)|\implies |1/g(z)|\leq |1/f(z)| $$
At this point I have some doubts. $|1/g(z)|\leq 2$ implies 
that $1/g$ is bounded and therefore $g$ is constant.

My doubt is about the following: if $|1/f(z)|\leq 2$ then $|1/g(z)|\leq 2$ ,since $|1/g(z)|\leq |1/f(z)|$. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Once we note that $|f(z)|\geq \mbox{Re}(f(z))>2$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$, we have that $f(z)\not=0$, and $g:=1/f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ with $|g(z)|<1/2$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Then, by [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), $g$ is constant and therefore also $1/g=f$ is constant.